# Swiper slider transition bug

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, carousel

I'm trying to make a slider using vueawesome slider (based on swiper slider). I'm trying to make it to look like [this](https://dribbble.com/shots/5715634-Website-Banner-Slides)

However for some reason the animation doesnt work when the swiper goes from the **first** element to the **second** element when it is past the **first** **loop**.

The transition is not seamless, it is just instant. If i remove all custom transition stuff and have it use the normal 300ms one it works fine. I've absolutely got no idea how to make it work and I've even tried using the coverflow effect but to no avail. I've also tried putting the animation on an inner container instead of the slide element itself but that just doesn't work either for some reason.

Template:

```
<swiper :options="swiperOption" ref="mySwiper">

    <!-- slides -->
    <swiper-slide class="swiper-1">
        <div class="inner">
            HELLOW 1
        </div>
    </swiper-slide>

    <swiper-slide>
        <div class="inner">
            HELLOW 2
        </div>
    </swiper-slide>

    <swiper-slide>
        <div class="inner">
            HELLOW 3
        </div>
    </swiper-slide>

    <!-- Optional controls -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"  slot="pagination"></div>
</swiper>
```

Swiperoptions:

```
swiperOption: {
            loop: true,
            grabCursor: false,
            slidesPerView:'auto',
            centeredSlides: true,
            autoplay: {
                delay: 2500,
                disableOnInteraction: false,
            },
}
```

Current styling:

```
 .swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 66px);
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    width:80% !important;
    transform: scale(.8) !important;
    transition: all 1500ms cubic-bezier(.85,1.54,.97,1.07) !important; 
}
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active{
    transform: scale(1) !important;
}
.swiper-slide .inner{
    background:blue;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Anyone who has any idea how to fix my issue?

EDIT
When i try to drag the swiper to go to the next slider there is an issue on the first slide where it plays the transition **twice**.

Live demo: [here (scroll down passed the header)](https://www.iamstijn.com/projects)

Thank you in advance~

Comment: Hi! Did u solve this? I have the same issue. When the loop start again, the first slide doent make the transition when i swipe to the second slide. I think is related with the duplicate slides, but i dont know how to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

I met the same issue just now. After some research, I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66634677/16300804) to solve my problem. You have to apply the CSS effect to the active duplicate slide also.

So this might solve your problem:

```
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-duplicate-active{
      transform: scale(1) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had definition of `cssMode` in the swiper initialization, when I removed it - the animation returned back.